# SAM Application runtime

Tags: aws-lambda, sam

So when I create an AWS SAM , I mostly have two options for a runtime, for ex.:

1. nodejs14.x
2. nodejs14.x (Image)

Second one is apparently a docker Image. I would like to know, is there any performance difference if I choose one over the other[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go with `nodejs14.x` unless you need to use a container - "performance" is subjective but if you don't need to use containers, don't use them as they will come with extra overhead.